# Connecting Django 1.5.4 to Mamp MySQL - Can't connect to local server

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, mamp

I'm trying to connect my Django app to a MAMP mysql database. I haven't used django in about a month and was surprised with the new database format. I'm not sure how to access my Mamp database.

***MAMP*** is running

MySQL is running & I have created a database on phpMyAdmin (called "tutorial")

***Django  settings.py***

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '~/tutorial.db'),
    }
}
```

This is the only thing that I have changed.

when I run $ python manage.py runserver 
I receive this error:

```
...
  File "/Users/Marcus/sites/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Marcus/sites/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")
```

Thanks

Comment: the database is really running on an ip and port that is reachable through Django? Firewall involved?

Comment: I'm confused by your comment, but the Mamp ports are the defaults (apache 8888, MySQL 8889) Anyway to include this?

Comment: is it our system or yours? check your system yourself and use your OS tools for checking ip addresses and used ports...close to a downvote...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question.
adding answer if anyone is still looking for an answer.

> Quick and easy solution is to create a symlink so OS can find the correct socket.

```
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```